# play idealize for Play Framework 2.1?

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.1

In Play 1.x there was the wonderful `play idealize` (and `play eclipsify`) that prepared a project file for a Play project in your favorite IDE.

I see that this was dropped in Play 2.X.

Any alternatives except doing it manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/IDE) the replacement is simply `play idea`.

Comment: Remember unlike  1.x where you import the project in Play2 you just need to `open` the project.

Answer (score 2):

In Play 2.x

**play idealize** is replaced with **play idea**

**play eclipsify** is replaced with **play eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

`play idea` works just fine for me in play 2.1.1

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. In Play 1, the command was `play idealize`